# For loop in js with function for starter

Tags: javascript, for-loop, alert

I have a job. Unfortunately I got stuck. Could you help me.
Project:

Ask a sentence of user analysis.
Ask to see which letters you want the user to count the block.
Count the number of times that the letter occurs in the sentence.
A pop-up window and then type the following sentence: "The letter X times Y occurs in this sentence."
Must be use function!
I write this:

```js
function bernardTheLetterCounter() {
  var sentence = prompt("Please type in the phrase to be examined");
  var letter = prompt("Please enter the letters were looking for.");

  for (i = 0; i <= sentence.length; i++) {
    if (sentence.charAt(i) == letter) {
      alert("The letter " + letter + " occurs " + sentence.charAt(i) + " times in this sentence.")
    }
  }
  return;
}


bernardTheLetterCounter();
```

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to finish the counting (the inside of the loop) then print the result after the loop is done. Like this:

```js
function bernardTheLetterCounter() {
  var sentence = prompt("Please type in the phrase to be examined");
  var letter = prompt("Please enter the letters were looking for.");

  var count = 0; // the counter (initialized to 0)
  // use var i instead of i (to make i local not global: this is just an advice)
  for (var i = 0; i <= sentence.length; i++) {
    if (sentence.charAt(i) == letter) { // if it is THE LETTER
      count++; // increment the counter (add 1 to counter)
    }
  }
  alert("The letter " + letter + " occurs " + count + " times in this sentence."); // use counter to print the result after the counting is done
  // the return here has no meaning
}


bernardTheLetterCounter();
```

What you was doing is printing a message every time the letter is found (which is ugly for the user, especially if the count of that letter is big).

Answer (score 0):

The function in this example can be re-used and tested. (ps. the for-loop is not a functional way of solving your problem).

```js
var sentence = prompt("Please type in the phrase to be examined:");
var letter = prompt("Please enter the letter you are looking for:");

function countLettersInString(source, letterToFind) {
  return source
    .split('')
    .filter(function(letter) { return letter === letterToFind; })
    .length;
}

console.log([
  'letter', letter,
  'was found', countLettersInString(sentence, letter),
  'times.'
].join(' '));
```